# how to work with path file correct,this is not easy

Tags: php, system, exec, shell-exec

Suppose I have a file in C:\Program Files\N.exe
I want to call system in php how to call it?
the path file should be write correct to return True and Not False

Clearance:
Suppose you can go to C:\Program Files through commandline
and then you can execute this file so it will run a program
Now instead of running it through commandline I want to run it through php
it has many choices

```
system
exec
shell_exec
passthru
```

It is not Important for me
I have problem using program files when it has space
how to write the path file?

Comment: You want to run an exe via php code ? This question is not very clear.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the exec command:

http://php.net/function.exec